# Play Url video in WPF MediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf

I get url form vimeo and i want to play on MediaElement but I have problem like this.

```
var FullVimeoUrl = "https://pdlvimeocdn-a.akamaihd.net/36507/517/262124023.mp4?token2=1428493810_25ff23eaeb9489b76649aaaf3e7fa438&aksessionid=028dcbd66a5e2a5a"

mediaElement.Source = new Uri(FullVimeoUrl.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
mediaElement.Play();
```

Problem:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object. Please help and solution for me thank.

Comment: Related: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: For future readers: this particular error is caused by bug in wpf media element which prevents it from playing http**s** urls. Change url to http and it will work.

Comment: @Evk thank you! I think it is the answer.

Comment: FYI now that WPF is open sourced, I logged a bug and planning on fixing this soon: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/722

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by your invalid URL:

> https://pdlvimeocdn-a.akamaihd.net/36507/517/262124023.mp4?token2=1428493810_25ff23eaeb9489b76649aaaf3e7fa438&aksessionid=028dcbd66a5e2a5a

If you try to view that in a browser (without your log in details), you'll find that the page will not load. Also the fact that it is an `https` address may also cause you a problem. If you try again with a publicly available video URL, you may have more luck.